# OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had spent the last couple hours trying to import the contents of a Excel File in to SQL using either OpenRowSet or OpenDataSource but am getting the same error.

I am currently using SQL Server 2014 X64, Excel 2016 64 bit, Windows Server 2008R2 64 bit

The code I am using is

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Data Source=S:\Refunds\file.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[test]
```

or

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0;Database=S:\Refunds\file.xlsx', [test])
```

And the error message I am getting is :-

Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "test". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

The assumption here is I am opening the files.xlsx file from the S:\ drive and looking at a tab called test

I have tried changing the path to the file to the full UNC path and tried moving the file to the C Drive as well but am still getting the same message, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Excel 12.0;Database=S:\Refunds\file.xlsx', [test$])
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried as suggested and it does appear to be doing something, well I am getting no error message.  I tried to load the contents in to a table and it just runs forever, there are only 402 rows in the Excel file so this should of completed in no time, any other thoughts?

Comment: You could try SELECT TOP 1000 FROM [test$] in stead of just [test$] - grasping a bit at straws.  Maybe the excel sheet is actually full of blank rows.